# Mysql Query within Query Loop

Tags: mysql

My Table structure looks like the following:

```
status_id | report_id | report_type | status | tech_id
        1 |         1 |           1 |      1 |      23
        2 |         1 |           1 |      2 |      23
        3 |         1 |           1 |      3 |      23
        4 |         1 |           1 |      4 |      23
        5 |         2 |           1 |      1 |      23
        6 |         2 |           1 |      2 |      23
        7 |         2 |           1 |      3 |      23
```

each record is a report status based on the report_id, report_type and tech_id.

I would like to select where tech_id = 23 and status = 3
The Query should only return 1 record being status_id "7" because the first record also has a status of "4"

I have tried JOINS, DISTINCT etc but can't get my head around this one,
Currently I am using a loop in PHP to get the correct result but it is messy and i am sure it should be possible with a single query.

Thanks

Comment: "because the first record also has a status of "4"
Is this a typo? the first record (ID 3) has a status of 3

Comment: What makes 7 the record to choose rather than 3? Because it is the highest status id?

Comment: why do you want only status_id = 7 ? do you want last added one? or max status_id? we cant help you unless you tell aout that

Comment: @WebberDepor correct i am looking for the max_status_id

Comment: have to apologize to WebberDepor, i am not looking for the max status_id, i was looking for the max status, Strawberry's solution below works perfectly, It is difficult to explain, but Strawberry got it. basically i am trying to get all the status = 3 where there is no status = 4 for the record_id. so in effect the Highest Status must be 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(report_id INT NOT NULL
,status INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(report_id,status)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(2,3);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.report_id = x.report_id 
   AND y.status = 4 
 WHERE x.status = 3 
   AND y.report_id IS NULL;
+-----------+--------+
| report_id | status |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |      3 |
+-----------+--------+
```

EDIT: Following the OP's late clarification...

```
SELECT report_id
     , MAX(status) status 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY report_id 
HAVING status = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select max(status_id) from table where tech_id = 23 and status = 3
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_max.asp